# Cannot get browsershot to work

Tags: php, node.js, laravel, npm, composer-php

Im trying to set up browsershot in laravel 5.4 to take a screenshot of a web page. I followed the instructions here: https://github.com/spatie/browsershot

So first i ran commands:

```
npm install puppeteer
composer require spatie/browsershot
```

And then in my code:

```
use Spatie\Browsershot\Browsershot;
dd(Browsershot::url('https://example.com')->screenshot());
```

But this just returns a empty string. Because there is no further feedback i dont know what else to try.

My setup is windows 10, php 7.2.2, node v8.9.4 and npm 5.6.0.

Answer (score 3):

You have to provide the path where to save the screenshot you took, as following example shows:

```
Browsershot::url('https://example.com')->save($pathToImage);
```

Comment: Here is the solution : https://jewelhuq.medium.com/how-to-install-laravel-browsershot-in-windows-using-xampp-138e897a756e